# IIS Web Application Allowing Anonymous Access Although this is Disabled

Tags: authentication, iis, basic-authentication, iis-8, httpmodule

Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8

I did some more diagnostics. What is it about this line in the web.config file which **overrides** the Authentication configuration specified in IIS?

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="Webhook" type="MyApp.Webhook" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I copied my Webhook folder to a Webgate folder and mapped the Webgate site to the Webgate folder. Through trial and error I can see that as long as that module is defined in the web.config file, the site can be accessed anonymously. As soon as I remove that line, I see the 401 Unauthorized on an anonymous request. Strange, why should the specification of my module which handles request, override the IIS specification which stipulates that request must be authenticated before they can be executed?

Here is the original question with the background on what I've been trying to do and the problem I've been having:

I have a web application - Webgate - set up to **Disallow** Anonymous access. Here's what this looks like:

[image: IIS Authentication Configuration]

The problem is, when I use Postman to interact with this application **without** any Authentication, the transaction succeeds. Here's what this looks like:

[image: Postman Anonymous POST]

How can this be?

One more screenshot to confirm that this is the application which answers to that URL:

[image: Site Binding]

Here is the one complexity, although I fail to see how this could have anything to do with the issue. Both Webgate and Webhook (see screenshot above) are two sites within IIS which are mapped to the same web application in the filesystem. Webgate is configured to insist on Authentication, Webhook is configured to allow Anonymous access. Again, I fail to see how Webhook's allowance of Anonymous access could have any impact on a transaction which comes in on the Webgate binding. Some background for context: Application capabilities when coming in via Webgate will be a superset of what is accessible via Webhook. Security can't be short-circuited by coming in on the wrong interface because transactions are checked at the application level to confirm whether the current transaction is identified or anonymous. The whole purpose of the two sites is so that accesses via the open interface - Webhook - are never challenged for identity, whereas transactions coming in on the protected interface - Webgate - are always challenged for Authentication.

I've done this before, although not recently, and I've never run into this problem. There is that little complexity, but bottom line, if a site is set up to disallow Anonymous access and insist on Basic Authentication, how are transactions getting through without being challenged? That is something I have never seen before. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Track down those 200 responses with FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis and you should be able to see how each modules/handlers participate and what might be wrong.

Comment: @LexLi Maybe I'm missing some basic information. If I implement an application as an HttpModule does that make me responsible for enforcing Authentication within my module? Or should I be able to rely on IIS to enforce Authentication before my module even sees the request?

Comment: If I put the application pool into Classic mode I get the expected IIS Basic Authentication as configured. If I put the pool into Integrated mode I do not see the expected Authentication. Is this expected behavior or is something misconfigured?

Comment: Like I said, collect FRT in both cases and compare. You cannot only see a lot but also clearly figure out the cause. That kind of investigation is much more useful than telling you "yes, expected" (though you might want to read things like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-integration-with-iis#aspnet-integration-architecture).

Comment: It showed me that, in Integrated mode, my module was being invoked before the Authentication module. That's not very useful! The truth is this server has too many sites on it and trying to get all the sites to coexist with their different  access needs, including WebDAV, anonymous, authenticated, etc. has become a bit of a house of cards. I will have to clean this up soon. In the meantime, I got this to work and I've spec'ed out the solution as the answer. The trick is in realizing how to set up one web.config file to serve two side-by-side applications, one Integrated and one Classic.

Comment: "my module was being invoked before the Authentication module" is a clear indicator that your module was not well written. Most modules should hook to events like `PostAuthenticateRequest` (in the article I referred to in the previous comment), so that they won't conflict with authentication, not `BeginRequest` or `AuthenticateRequest` which is likely to be the one used by your module.

Comment: Yes, you are so right!!! My problem is I am building onto the wrong Webhook. This one was designed for open access so it's not suitable for what I am trying to do. I actually have another Webhook which I wrote for authenticated access so long ago that I'd forgotten its fundamental construction. Exactly as you propose - it does some pre-transactional logging in  OnBeginRequest, but it won't do any actual 'work'  until OnPostAuthenticateRequest is called. Thank you! I believe this orients me toward the solution. If you post it, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: And to make it worse, I was calling ctx.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() at the end of OnBeginRequest so of course no authentication was happening. Embarrassed! But anyway, after shifting my processing into OnPostAuthenticateRequest everything is working exactly as expected. My two sites are mapped to the same application folder and they are both running in the same Integrated application pool. Everything exactly the same except one insists on authentication and the other does not. Please post as the answer. You deserve the credit! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Issue Revisited

To summarize what we learned so far,

- You wrote a managed module for ASP.NET.
- This module hooks to pipeline event `OnBeginRequest` to perform some business logic and calls `ctx.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` when finishing.
- Anonymous authentication was used on IIS side.

Everything works fine there, but you found that,

- When Basic authentication is used on IIS side things started to break in integrated pipeline mode
- Switching back to classic mode seems to solve it.

### The Cause

Your module works in classic mode no matter what authentication method is used, because the whole ASP.NET pipeline runs behind IIS authentication module.

However, integrated mode works differently from classic mode, where your module no longer executes behind authentication but ahead of.

You confirmed that by collecting FRT.

### The Solution

Like we discussed, the solution is to simply change your module so that it hooks to `OnPostAuthenticateRequest` instead.

### References

- Microsoft published the pipeline changes in [an important article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-integration-with-iis#aspnet-integration-architecture), so everyone should get familiar with the details.
- Migrating from classic to integrated requires [a good guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis)
- FRT is [always a handy helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) for module/handler developers

Comment: My sequence of events was slightly different but the summation is technically accurate. I had always had my application in Pipeline mode and everything worked because all application features were published to anonymous access. I did everything from OnBeginRequest and never noticed the technical deficiency. When I began to publish features requiring Authentication I noticed that the request was never challenged even though IIS was configured to do so. We now know why.  (Everything in the interim was my attempt to solve a problem without understanding the root cause. :-\) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @YossiGeretz revised it to match your description.